# Installing glut on visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, freeglut

I'm trying to compile the freeglut utilities from http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/install.php Compiling instructions are not provided for Visual Studio 2013 and I don't see any solution file, nor a visual studio folder.

Comment: "It's not *that* hard..."  Bahahaha.  Cough.  Use a prebuilt version as recommended in [this web page](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/315/WWW/Lab1/GLUT/windows.html).  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for windows are provided in README.win32 and it seems to support being built with cygwin or mingw only.

Frankly I would create my own vcxproj for it and add the cpp files indicated by the buildscripts manually until it builds. That will, at least, ensure that the resulting dll uses the same c-runtime settings as the rest of my Visual Studio projects, produces MSVC compatible libs etc.

Alternatively the freeglut download page does link some 3rd party pre-compiled windows binaries that will either be very convenient to use - or a total @!! ache if its built with a c-runtime linkage that disagrees with your project.